# Working with Entity Framework 6 Transactions

Tags: entity-framework, transactions, azure-sql-database

I have a set of questions regarding the use of transactions in EF 6. I use the following code template for my database queries:

```
using (var ctx = new MyContext(connectionString))
{
    using (var tx = ctx.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Snapshot))
    {
          try
          {
               // query database
               ctx.SaveChanges();
               tx.Commit();
          }
          catch(Exception ex)
          {
               tx.Rollback();

               if(ex is A) // handle A
               if(ex is B) // handle B                   

               throw;
          }
    } 
}
```

- I will be querying the database only once and invoking `SaveChanges()` only once. Is there any need to rollback the transaction if an exception occurs?
- Some of my transactions will only be reading data, so I won't be invoking `SaveChanges()`. In this case, should I still be calling `Commit()`?
- I'm thinking of using `SqlAzureExecutionStrategy` for connection resiliency. At one point do transient failures occur? Is it only during the execution of the query or the invocation of `SaveChanges()`? How about the initialization of `ctx`, `tx`, and calling of `Commit()`? Can they cause such failures?
- Is there a less compact way of querying the database inside of a transaction? For every single query, I need to use the above code template which significantly duplicates code such as the two using statements, try-catch block, and generic exception handling. I believe the last one can be achieved by deriving from `SqlAzureExecutionStrategy` or `DbExecutionStrategy`. I'm all for refactoring code as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

**You dont have to actually use transactions in Entity Framework.**

> The default isolation mode is read committed and fits perfectly to 99% of your needs, eg. reading data. When you want to save the changes you made to the database (Create, Update, Delete), EntityFramework is smart enough to create a transaction without your notice behind the scenes to wrap the changes. You can be sure that everything will be saved or every change will be discarded (Atomicity).

Look Here https://coderwall.com/p/jnniww

- When you make the call to SaveChanges, I believe the Entity Framework will perform all those operations in a single transaction. And when excpetion occurs, it rollbacks automatically. So, you dont have to call rollback. or use transaction.
- Entity Framework has handled transactions internally, you can use it when you have to do operations on multiple databases
- I am unaware about this `SqlAzureExecutionStrategy for connection resiliency`. But, this feature is complemented by the new ADO.Net idle connection resiliency in .NET Framework 4.5.1 http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/10/17/net-framework-4-5-1-rtm-gt-start-coding.aspx

The Basic Entity Framework Operations Block..

```
using (var context = new ProductContext()) 
{ 
    try
    {
        // Perform data access using the context 
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //handle exception
    }

}
```

Hope it may Help you, Have a nice day.

Comment: I know the default transaction provided by EF does not protect against non-repeatable reads and phantom rows.

Comment: There also may be scenarios where you need to encompass multiple `context.SaveChanges()` within a broader transaction.